# Как проставить дату изменения листа на другие листы Excel

Tags: excel

Есть книга Excel, в ней нное количество листов. На каждом  листе есть ячейка с датой изменения. Прежде дата обновлялась макросом

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim rng1 As Range
Set rng1 = Intersect([A4:L22], Target)
If rng1 Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
Application.EnableEvents = False
[B2] = Format(Now(), "dd-mm-yyyy")
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Появилась необходимость проставлять дату изменений на всех листах. То есть, если вносились изменения на листе 1, дата должна быть проставлена на всех прочих листах. То же самое - для прочих листов.

Answer (score 0):

Разместите код в модуле книги

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal sht As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Application.Intersect(Range("A4:L22"), Target) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False

        For Each sht In Worksheets
            sht.Range("B2").Value = Format(Now(), "dd-mm-yyyy")
        Next sht

        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```